# No Captcha Recaptcha is Not Displaying

Tags: recaptcha

I'm upgrading to the NoCaptcha reCaptcha as described on [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display).

I'm using the Automatic Render method.

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='PUBLIC_KEY'></div>
    ...
</body>
```

However, it displays like this:
[image: Post Render Widget]
Where the Widget should live, it looks like this:
[image: Space where Widget should be]
It successfully pings https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js and downloads recaptcha__en.js. If I use the deferred render from the example, it gets the same result. There are no errors reported in the console and no errors in the network responses.

The iFrame does have code generated in it, it just doesn't display. How can I make the widget display properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a few days and playing with CSP to figure it out but it turned out one of the stylesheets was disabling the iframe.

I found this in my code which was no longer being used.

```
iframe {
    height:0px;
    display:none;
}
```

While the code would write to the frame and download the right Javascript, because there was no displayed iFrame, there was no where for the Captcha to write.